# Automatically click button when site is created

Tags: sharepoint-online, modern-experience, flow, power-automate

We use a SharePoint app to sign documents in our SharePoint sites. On each new site the app needs to be activated by simply clicking on two buttons. We use a lot of sites in our SharePoint environment.

Is it possible to automate this task by using some kind of a Power Automate flow that runs each time a site is created?

The button that needs to be clicked in the menu bar of a document library.

Answer (score 1):

You can run a Power automate flow automatically when a site is created in SharePoint online using site template (design) and site script functionality.

Check below documentations for more information:

1. [SharePoint site template and site script overview](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/site-design-overview)
2. [Calling Power Automate from a site script](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/site-design-trigger-flow-tutorial)
3. [Site design JSON schema - Trigger a flow](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/site-design-json-schema#trigger-a-flow)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But it didn't answer my question. I need to know how I can create an script that clicks the button to configure the app

Comment: What do you mean by "configure the app"? I thought you want to run a power automate flow when new site is created. It is possible using site template (design) and site script functionality as mentioned in my answer. You can find the script/JSON schema in 3rd link in my answer & you can find information about how to create site template/script in 1st link.

Comment: Hi you can forget my question. I found an other solution.

Comment: Great, glad you found the solution. You can also answer your own question & explain how you achieved it. It might help others with similar question in future.